# Why can I jump multiple times, even tho I set up no extra jumps?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wrote this script and for some reason I can jump up to 2 times after leaving the ground. Its really weird, because, as you can see maxJumps is set to one.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float speed = 8f;
    private float jumpingPower = 16f;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;
    private bool isGrounded = false;
    public float maxJumps = 1;
    private float currentJumps;

    public float coyoteTimerMax = .03f;
    private float coyoteTimer;

    private float jumpBuffer;
    public float maxJumpBuffer = .04f;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jumpBuffer = maxJumpBuffer;
        }
        

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            currentJumps = 0; 
            coyoteTimer = coyoteTimerMax;
            
        }
        else
        {
            coyoteTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            
        }

        jumpBuffer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (jumpBuffer > 0 && coyoteTimer > 0 && currentJumps < maxJumps)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
            currentJumps++;
            jumpBuffer = 0; // Reset the jump buffer after successfully jumping
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
        }

        
        

        

        Flip();

        
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }

        private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I think is happening:

1. You press space, which makes you jump
2. You jump and currentJumps increases by 1, to 1
3. **(Here is the important part):** The next frame comes so fast that you don't leave the ground yet. This causes currentJumps to be reset to 0 because it still is grounded.

What you could do to fix this is to change this part to be:

```
        if (jumpBuffer > 0 && coyoteTimer > 0 && currentJumps < maxJumps)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
            currentJumps++;
            isGrounded = false;
            jumpBuffer = 0; // Reset the jump buffer after successfully jumping
        }
```

This way, it sets isGrounded to false immediately after you jump. Next frame, it won't set currentJumps to 0, because isGrounded = false.

You might still want to keep OnCollisionExit2D, because it would set isGrounded to false if you are falling, but not from a jump.

If you have any questions, you can leave a comment.

Comment: I have one other question tho, do you know how I can prevent the player from walljumping because the collider is touching the edge of a platform?

Comment: @Noyokay. There are two options: **1.** You could change the tag of the wall so that it doesn't register as a "Ground" object. You could could change it to "Wall" or something. One downside to this is that it would require you to make multiple GameObjects. **2.** Alternatively, you could set up a raycast system or a child GameObject to the player which has a trigger collider on it. (These are what I would do if I were you). Maybe this video might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxCVHBMdTWo